# Why are this integral's result different depending on what way you integrate it?

Tags: integration

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but me and my classmates are in a dilema.
$$\int \tan^{3}x + \tan x dx$$

If I do it using integration by parts it returns $$\frac{1}{2} \cos^{2}(x) + C$$ and if I do it with subtitution it returns $$\frac{\tan ^{2}x}{2} + C$$.
My teacher said that the results must be somehow equivalent but he didn't demonstrated anything related to this.
Also... some online integration tools return one of the results, some return the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x = \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 x}$, we see that $\dfrac{\tan^2{x}}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2\cos^2 x}$.

So, $\dfrac{\tan^2{x}}{2}+C = \dfrac{1}{2\cos^2 x}+C'$ where the constants $C$ and $C'$ are related by $C = C' + \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Thus, these two results are equivalent.

Another way to see that both results are correct is to show that the derivative of both answers is the integrand, i.e. $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{\tan^2{x}}{2}+C\right] = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{1}{2\cos^2 x}+C'\right] = \tan^3x + \tan x$. I'll let you work this out yourself, but I'll leave you the hint that the trig identities $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$ and $\dfrac{1}{\cos x} = \sec x$ will be useful.